# Mean of a column in table, Matlab

Tags: matlab, datatable, mean

I'd like to calculate standard deviations and variances of columns in a table but I get NaN instead. So i looked at the summary, the result for first column is as follows:

```
summary(churn0Table)

Variables:

rev_Mean: 50438x1 double
    Values:

        min       -6.1675   
        median     48.876   
        max        1223.4   
        NaNs          112
```

but when I write

```
mean1 = mean(churn0Table{:,1},1)
```

i see NaN as a result. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: What would you expect the mean of a bunch of data containing `NaN`s to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use functions that ignore nan values, see [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/summary-statistics-for-data-with-missing-values.html).

There you can find that `nanstd` and `nanvar` should give you the desired results.

---

If you dont have the Statistics Toolbox, you can mimic these functions by considering only the non-nan values yourself using `~isnan(.)`.

Comment: It worked well on most of my data but there are few columns that i need to use as categorical and it gives error on them saying "Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'categorical' ".